# Page code showing in WP Dashboard

Tags: shortcode, dashboard

I couldn't find this issue on here even that I looked hard. If it is than I do apologize.

I've made a shortcode for my WP. When I put the shortcode an a page than the code is also visible on top of the page editor in the dashboard.

How can I prevent this? Did I do something wrong in my code? See below for code.
[image]

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sollicitatie_formulier' ) ) {
        function sollicitatie_formulier(){
            global $wpdb;
            if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
            { 
            $table = tbl_uploads;
            $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['afile']['size'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['afile']['type'];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'];
            $folder="wp-content/themes/jobify-extended/uploads/";
            $data = array(
                'voornaam' => $_POST['avoornaam'],
                'familienaam' => $_POST['afamilienaam'],
                'comment' => $_POST['amsg'],
                'afile' => rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'],
                'size' => $_FILES['afile']['size'],
                'type' => $_FILES['afile']['type'],



            );

            // new file size in KB
            $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
            // new file size in KB

            // make file name in lower case
            $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
            // make file name in lower case

            $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

            $format = array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            );

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
            {
                $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format,$folder);
                if($success){
                ?>
                    <script>
                    alert('successfully uploaded');
                    window.location.href='sollicitatie-formulier?success';
                    </script>
    <?php

}
}
}


else   {
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="voornaam">Voornaam: </label><input type="text" name="avoornaam" required="">
        <label for="familienaam">Familienaam: </label><input type="text" name="afamilienaam" required="">
        <label for="comment">bericht: </label><textarea type="text" name="amsg"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="afile" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn-upload" value="upload"</input>
        </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['success']))
        {
    ?>
        <label>Kandidaat succesvol toegevoegd...  <a href="/bekijk/">click hier om kandidaten te bekijken.</a></label>
        <?php
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
    {
        ?>
        <label>Oeps...een probleem! Probeer opnieuw</label>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <label>Try to upload any files(PDF, DOC, DOCX)</label>

 <?php } }

        }
    }

    add_shortcode( 'sollicitatie_formulier', 'sollicitatie_formulier' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcodes should not *echo* any output. They should always *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.

You either write the html code on a variable:

```
function my_shortcode() {
    $output = '<div>something</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Or you can use php output buffering:

```
function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); ?> 
    <div>something</div> 
    <?php 
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

In your case, you could put ob_start at the beginning of the function and in the end just return ob_get_clean:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sollicitatie_formulier' ) ) {
        function sollicitatie_formulier(){
            global $wpdb;

            ob_start();

            if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
            { 
            $table = tbl_uploads;
            $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['afile']['size'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['afile']['type'];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'];
            $folder="wp-content/themes/jobify-extended/uploads/";
            $data = array(
                'voornaam' => $_POST['avoornaam'],
                'familienaam' => $_POST['afamilienaam'],
                'comment' => $_POST['amsg'],
                'afile' => rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'],
                'size' => $_FILES['afile']['size'],
                'type' => $_FILES['afile']['type'],



            );

            // new file size in KB
            $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
            // new file size in KB

            // make file name in lower case
            $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
            // make file name in lower case

            $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

            $format = array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            );

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
            {
                $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format,$folder);
                if($success){
                ?>
                    <script>
                    alert('successfully uploaded');
                    window.location.href='sollicitatie-formulier?success';
                    </script>
    <?php

}
}
}


else   {
    ?>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="voornaam">Voornaam: </label><input type="text" name="avoornaam" required="">
        <label for="familienaam">Familienaam: </label><input type="text" name="afamilienaam" required="">
        <label for="comment">bericht: </label><textarea type="text" name="amsg"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="afile" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn-upload" value="upload"</input>
        </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['success']))
        {
    ?>
        <label>Kandidaat succesvol toegevoegd...  <a href="/bekijk/">click hier om kandidaten te bekijken.</a></label>
        <?php
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
    {
        ?>
        <label>Oeps...een probleem! Probeer opnieuw</label>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <label>Try to upload any files(PDF, DOC, DOCX)</label>

 <?php } }

        return ob_get_clean();

        }
    }

    add_shortcode( 'sollicitatie_formulier', 'sollicitatie_formulier' );
```

Comment: I really want to understand this. So where in my code do I put your  code as I don't use <div>. I don't understand. sorry I'm new to WordPress.

Comment: I edited my answer with your code.

Comment: Nice! It's gone. So I need to do this everytime when I write a similar function?

Comment: Yes, the main thing is that you need to return the html. If you echo directly the html you'll have those kind of problems.

Comment: And if you want to have a more organised function you can put the shortcode on another file, and then just include the file inside the shortcode function, like this: function myshortcode() { ob-start(); include 'file.php'; return ob_get_clean(); }

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your help. I've learned a lot!

Comment: When I make it cleaner and use your suggestion `function myshortcode() { ob-start(); include 'file.php'; return ob_get_clean(); }` Do I than still need to include `ob-start();` in `file.php`?

Comment: No, you don't need. Just on the function. The same for ob_get_clean()

Comment: And do I just put [sollicitatie_formulier] on my page? What I did was I made a folder called `scripts`and put in there my php file. Than in my `functions.php` I did `function sollicitatie_formulier() { 
        ob-start(); 
        include 'scripts/solliciteer-form.php'; 
        return ob_get_clean(); 
        
    }`but that doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60769/discussion-between-dbeja-and-wouters).